# How to prove (p^q) ^ ( q -> r ) <-> r using Z- notation?

Tags: formal-methods, z-notation

I am trying to prove logical expressions using Z-notations. But, I am new to the Z language. Please help me to prove the above logical expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do it using Z notation language which is used as a language for formal specifiaction.

1st Step : Introduction of Conjunction

```
(p ∧ q) ∧ ( q⇒r)  [ ∧ - elim2]
```

2nd Step: We will have:

```
 q ⇒ r
```

3rd step: We want get q is true:

```
p ∧ q     [ ∧ - elim2]
------
   q
```

4th step: Using q and q=>r we can say that r is true.

For futher information please refer to [this book](http://www.usingz.com/usingz.pdf) "using Z".

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it will be very understandable if there is a tree of proof steps.